# How to split strings by only the first special character that's within the string?

Tags: python, regex, string, list, split

I'd like to split the below string by only the first equal sign in that string

String:

```
 s= 'ButtonParams=U3ViamVjdCxFbWFpbA=='
```

Desired_String:

```
 s= ['ButtonParams','U3ViamVjdCxFbWFpbA==']
```

When I do s.split("="), I get the following, which is what I do not want:

```
s.split("=")
['ButtonParams', 'U3ViamVjdCxFbWFpbA', '', '']
```

I need to run this function across a list of strings where this is the case, so scalability is important here.

Comment: Have you read the documentation for `split()`?

Comment: Hey but why've you added [tag:regex]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) accepts an optional "maxsplit" parameter: if you set it to `1` it will split on the first `=` character it finds and return the remainder of the string:

```
>>> s.split('=', 1)
['ButtonParams', 'U3ViamVjdCxFbWFpbA==']
```

Answer (score 3):

`s.split("=", maxsplit=1)` is the best but

```
import re
print (re.split('=',s,1))
```

The output is

```
['ButtonParams', 'U3ViamVjdCxFbWFpbA==']
```

As you have tagged [regex](/questions/tagged/regex)

A little deviation from the post

If the expected output was `['ButtonParams', 'U3ViamVjdCxFbWFpbA']` then you can have the following liscos (list comprehensions)

- `[i for i in s.split('=') if i is not '']`
- `[i for i in s.split('=') if i ]` (Contributed by Adam Smith)

Comment: in desired output `U3ViamVjdCxFbWFpbA` has `==` at end

Comment: @AdamSmith That won't work out as the OP expected something else. Check the edit. :P

Comment: no reason at all to use regex here. I liked your other answer better, even if it wasn't the same expected output! :)

Comment: @AdamSmith Thanks for the review. Check if this answer suits well

Answer (score 1):

`str.split` accepts an optional argument `maxsplit` which determines how many splits (maximally) to make, e.g.:

```
"ButtonParams=U3ViamVjdCxFbWFpbA==".split("=", maxsplit=1)
# ['ButtonParams', 'U3ViamVjdCxFbWFpbA==']
```